# How to set domain name in Crunchbang GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, gnu, crunchbang

How can I set the domain name in GNU/Linux?, I am using Crunchbang and I need to set the domain name for my LAN network.

EDIT:
Let me talk more about my problem:
I need to configure a LAN network for three or four PCs with GNU/Linux(college project):

```
PC1: acting as server  -- hostname = "server"     -- GNU/Linux Debian Squeeze
PC2: client 1          -- hostname = "crunchbang" -- GNU/Linux Crunchbang
PC3: client 2          -- hostname = "acer"       -- GNU/Linux Debian Squeeze
```

Crunchbang is based on debian then "I think" there is no much difference.

I am guiding me with this [document](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lan/index.html) and there says that the domain name for all hosts in the network must be the same.

The OS in PC1 and PC3 are fresh installations, Crunchbang is the OS what my friend have in his laptop.

When I installed debian in PC1 and PC3 I set the domain name and the host name but now only the last is present.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to qualify what you mean by "set the domain name" - there are at least three completely different interpretations of "domain" that might apply.

1. You want to set the Windows Domain the system will use for SMB networking.

   I don't know offhand how to do this, but it would probably involve editing your Samba configuration; http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html#ads-member would probably be a good place to start looking
2. You want to set the default DNS name (lookup)

   llua's answer above sets the domain component of the hostname, but if you want `ping myhost` to find myhost in the local DNS domain, let's say it is accounting.example.com, you need a search line in /etc/resolv.conf, for example:

   ```
   search accounting.example.com
   ```

   On some systems, /etc/resolv.conf is managed by the resolvconf system (this is true on my Ubuntu system, not sure about Debian in general or Crunchbang in particular) - if /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf then you should probably be editing /etc/network/interfaces, which should contain a stanza like this:

   ```
   iface eth0 inet static
              address 192.0.2.3
              netmask 255.255.255.0
              gateway 192.0.2.1
              dns-nameservers 192.0.2.1 198.51.100.1
              dns-search accounting.example.com example.com
   ```

   If you use DHCP to set up the local networking configuration, the DHCP daemon should set up both the local hostname and the DNS resolver search path automatically - you may find that is a better solution than either llua's or mine, at least if there is a local DHCP server and it is properly configured to provide DNS search information.
3. You want to set the NIS (YP) domain name, used for passwd/group/hosts/etc. lookups on some systems with NFS file sharing set up.

   You might do this by editing /etc/domainname, and/or immediately (but temporarily) with the `domainname NISNAME` command.  Note that the NIS domain name need not be the same as the DNS domain name (indeed some recommend that it not be), although at least in some cases the NIS domain name will be set automatically to the domain component of the hostname if not otherwise configured.

Comment: I have added more info in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

edit `/etc/hostname`

```
<hostname>.<domainname>
```

Then edit your `/etc/hosts`

```
  127.0.0.1 <hostname>.<domainname> <hostname>
```

Comment: Nope! That don't work!

Comment: Restart the computer? If is that, yes, I have restarted my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Change the New Values in  the Host file

```
[root@erp ~]# cat /etc/hosts
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.0.1        erp.myappsdba.com  erp
[root@erp ~]#
```

Step2: Change the New Values in  the network file

```
[root@erp ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=erp.myappsdba.com
GATEWAY=192.168.0.3
```

Step3: Change the New Values in  the sysctl.conf and resolv.conf files

```
[root@erp ~]## cat /etc/sysctl.conf
kernel.hostname=erp.myappsdba.com
kernel.domainname=myappsdba.com

[root@erp etc]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search myappsdba.com
nameserver 192.168.0.7
nameserver 192.168.0.2
option attemts : 5
option timeout :15
[root@erp etc]#
```

Step4:Ping the Host Name or Changed IP Address.

```
[root@erp etc]# ping myappsdba.com
PING myappsdba.com (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fortedc.myappsdba.com (192.168.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.06 ms
```

Step5:Restart the Network or Reboot the system for effecting the changes

```
[root@erp ~]# init 6
```

or

```
[root@erp ~]# service network restart
```

Comment: +1 I don't use Crunchbang anymore so I can't verify you answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try making changes to either

1)

/etc/rc.sysinit or /etc/sysconfig/network (if it supports sysconfig style of configuration);

2) Run network-admin as root and make the changes via GUI
network-admin

&

confirm with /bin/hostname command

3) eitherways, making changes to /etc/hostname with  format and then restart the network service should help.

Comment: I would add to the mix the `/etc/resolve.conf`, since all of those files change are recommended. I think that part one of you answer is for Redhat based only.